# Grep: looking for pattern only if *not behind* another pattern

Tags: grep

I try to get grep to find a pattern only if it's *not behind* another pattern. 
So, for instance, in the three lines below, I'm looking for `foo` if not behind `#` (you guess why :-)

`1./make_maps_meteo_ecmwf.pl:#  foo`

`2./make_maps_meteo_ecmwf.pl: foo`

`3./make_maps_meteo_ecmwf.pl: foo #`

I need lines 2 and 3, not 1.

this does not help:

`grep '[^#].*foo'`

piped grep won't help because it will exclude line 3

`grep 'foo' | grep -v '#'`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `#` before `foo`:

```
$ grep "^[^#]*foo" file
2./make_maps_meteo_ecmwf.pl: foo
3./make_maps_meteo_ecmwf.pl: foo #
```

Comment: Funny! We must have a different shell, because your solution returns 2. while `grep "^[^#].*foo" file` return 2. and 3. Actually, I expected this pattern to match only lines _not starting with #_  . Anyway, thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: If you have the `.` in the regex, it does match lines _not starting with #_.

Comment: Ok thanks; I'll keep that in the back of my mind. Thanks  :-)